# How to query different row with where conditions on same table without using a subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server

I currently have a very large query with lots and lots of sub queries for transforming data for migration.

The tables I am joining have many rows of information (some 200k+, some 500k+) and obviously the way I am doing sub queries is increasing the complexity exponentially.

The schema is not important but I am at the point where adding one more sub query takes the query execution time from ~1 minute to what I can only assume based on how slowly the rows are going up will be many hours.

I know I can use a window function to query the same table/tables but am unsure how to structure it to get the result I want.

The row of information I want is in a table that is already joined to my query, I just need to use a value from the current row I am on to get an id of another row in the already joined table.

I am using SQL Server 2017.

I tried a sub query, which will probably work although it will take hours/days now.

```
create table dbo.sm (
  id varchar(max) primary key,
  apn varchar(max)
)
create table dbo.gi (
  global_id varchar(max) primary key,
  au_stock_code varchar(max)
)

insert into dbo.sm 
values
('a', 'b'),
('b', 'abcdefgh')

insert into dbo.gi 
values
(1, 'a'),
(2, 'b')

select
  gi.global_id, 
  sm.id,
  (select global_id from dbo.gi where au_stock_code  = sm.apn)
from dbo.sm sm
left join dbo.gi gi on sm.id = gi.au_stock_code
```

and example output row would be:

```
1 - 'a' - 2
```

Comment: We need a [mre] with sample data, desired results and your attempt.

Comment: "I know I can use a window function to query the same table/tables but am unsure how to structure it to get the result I want." that's probably the real answer, but we can't help you without further info.

Comment: Are you sure that code is for SQL Server 2017? It doesn't run in it. See [modified fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/xtDdDG6z).

Comment: The sample data produces two rows in the result, not 1 row.

Comment: Based on what you have shown, its unlikely you can avoid a sub-query, because your join is on a completely different condition, so the value you are looking for may or may not exist elsewhere in the resultset. As the answer shows you can join again to avoid a sub-query, but that is unlikely to perform any different, because its likely to produce a very similar query plan.

Comment: Please may I suggest you actually read the [mre] link? It will help you make better questions, but is also a good skill to have for diagnostics, unit tests, etc, etc.

Comment: Do you have index on the joined fields

Comment: No index's, these are tables pulled down and copied off a prod server and just copied with select into

Answer (score 0):

You can join on to the same table multiple times. To diffentiate between the different "instances" of the table, aliases are used...

```
select
    gi.au_stock_code, 
    sm.id,
    sc.global_id
from
  dbo.sm sm
left join
  dbo.gi gi
    on gi.au_stock_code = sm.id
left join
  dbo.gi sc
    on sc.au_stock_code = sm.apn
```

Comment: Its most likely going to perform the same as a sub-query though - which is really what OPs question is about.

Answer (score 0):

You need another index for your query to work efficiently. This is both for the subquery and for a join.

```sql
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX gi_stock_code ON gi
  (au_stock_code) INCLUDE (global_id);
```